# How to cache processed history with git subtree split

Tags: git, git-subtree

Given my history is
`commit1 -> commit2 -> commit3 (HEAD, master)`

Now I want to do a subtree split, git need to run from `commit1`, then `commit2`, then `commit3`, which is fine.

Later I add commit4, so now my history is:
`commit1 -> commit2 -> commit3 -> commit4 (HEAD, master)`

Now I do another subtree split, git is running all the way through form `commit1` again, where as it can just continue from `commit3` instead.

Is that something can be achieved?

Comment: I think you're interested in option `--rejoin`. `git subtree split` should start with the commit created by previous `--rejoin`.